# wp-query problem with author

Tags: wp-query

I run the query:

```
SELECT post_author
FROM  `wp_posts`
```

and see that many posts have as author the value 1.

I then execute in my search.php the following:

```
$args = array(   
    'author' => 1,                            
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

and get no results!
Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I realized the problem:

while ($the_query-> have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();;

it now works OK